# Casting a different close vote after retracting one

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

This is a generic question (however I can provide a specific example if needed). There are often cases when question should be closed for lacking MCVE. However, reasonable OP will take this into account and edit the question, adding the required example.

At this point, one should reasonably retract close vote, but, if later (as evident from future comments, next edits, etc) the question would need to be closed again (for becoming a duplicate, for example) it won't be possible for the original voter to vote to close it again.

Is it expected? Shouldn't vote counter be reset after edit, the same way as one can change the score of the question after edit?